# Post method receiving value as invalid value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Via $.post method I am submitting an ID number to PHP server. Visually in Google Chrome I see the value is correctly sent, but in PHP server debug I see the value is received with unknown extra value added.

PHP:

`$rrn = str_replace('"',"",$_POST['rrn']);`
`$sql = "select *From sh_av_spidcard where rrn='{$rrn}' limit 1";`

sending value was `10224440075` but there is two unknown value getting added `\u000` what is that? and how to fix it?

Debug on Browser console:

[image]
[image]

EDIT:

JavaScript:

```
  input  = input.replace(/^\s*|\s*$/g, "");
  input  = input.replace(/^\s*/g, "");
  input  = input.replace(/\s*$/g, "");
```

PHP:

```
$aChr = array(
        "\u0000", "\u0001", "\u0002", "\u0003", "\u0004",
        "\u0005", "\u0006", "\u0007", "\u0008", "\u0009", "\u000A",
        "\u000B", "\u000C", "\u000D", "\u000E", "\u000F", "\u0010", "\u0011",
        "\u0012", "\u0013", "\u0014", "\u0015", "\u0016", "\u0017", "\u0018",
        "\u0019", "\u001A", "\u001B", "\u001C", "\u001D", "\u001E", "\u001F"
);
$sChr = implode($aChr); 
$rrn = str_replace('"',"",$_POST['rrn']);
$rrn = str_replace($sChr, "", $rrn);
```

[image]

Comment: \u000 is NULL if that helps with diagnosing the issue...

Comment: Are there columns holding the value NULL adjacent to the ID that are getting pulled back by the SELECT *?

Comment: Please see my EDIT, yes the column is NULL in db. Also i updated the PHP post code but still failing. because there is \u0002 and \u0003 coming from where no idea.

Comment: Hm. I haven't seen another issue yet, but have you tried "$clean = preg_replace('/[^\PC\s]/u', '', $input);" for removing control characters? I saw your replacement table already which seems to achieve a similar thing

Comment: that is also failing, please see my EDIT, before sending to PHP, already removed the control characters via Javascript but still its happening.

Comment: @Darren, "Select *From" is unusual, but valid syntax.

Comment: @Hiphop03199 Just checked lol, it's too early for me :( hahaha

Comment: That's alright, I had to check it myself after you said that, but I had assumed it was fine beforehand

Comment: Its working when i did on PHP: $rrn = preg_replace('/[^\PC\s]/u', '', $rrn); and Javascript my EDIT section. But still not sure why it was not working without this line $rrn = preg_replace('/[^\PC\s]/u', '', $rrn); ?

Comment: Well that line just lazily removes the unicode escape characters. But it feels like a band-aid since we're not sure what the underlying issue is, and how those control chars got there :/

Comment: I don't think you wanted to implode $aChr to use it in the str_replace (I might be wrong here). I think you want $aChr in place of $sChr in this line "$rrn = str_replace($sChr, "", $rrn);" (This is outdated now you're using the preg replace). https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php